# WP7 - Silverlight (Performance and Number of pages)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

I am asking this because I couldn't find an answer on the internet. I don't have much experience on application building and silverlight.

My questions is: Does it effect the performance of the application if I have many pages (around 60pages) with sounds.

I am planning to create a small game with story which will be based on around 50 jpeg images (800x480px) and there will be different choices for the gamer which will lead to different endings(pages). I chose to use blend rather than building it on XNA because it was easy for me to create link between pages(if it is wrong decision please inform me :)).

Does this method effect the game performance(loading,speed etc.)?, Am I doing lame work(it looks like lame actually :/)?

Is there a way to do it in XNA more efficiently? If yes could you please give me keywords for me to work and search for it.

Thank you in advance for your patience and interest on this noob question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Performance is not affect. you only use additional memory. M$ asks you to respect the 90MB limit for the app in terms of memory ( isolated storage doesn't have a limit on data storage)
2. Creating navigation between pages is rather easy,  you can create the links in Blend and see the code there as well. In Blend you won't get intellisense (auto-complete features ). Navigation between pages is handled by navigation service. NavigationService.NavigateTo
3. In general if your game doesn't have much of graphics in it, why don't you stick to silverlight. With XNA there is a learning curve.... you might need to learn the ropes before you can get around it.